# Multiple entities in a single-page form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I've got an issue where I can't get more than one model to display in a view, specifically in a form. The approach I've been taking so far is to use one "parent" view to hold multiple partial views that relate to the various models (using EF6, VS13).

However, through wrong implementation or understanding, I can't seem to make this work, as I keep getting the error that each view can only relate to one model.

--**Models**--

NewHire:

```
namespace HROnboarding.Domain.Entities
{
    public class NewHire
    {
        public int NewHireId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Needs Phone")]
        public bool NeedsPhone { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Needs Computer")]
        public bool NeedsComputer { get; set; } //Enables SoftwareNeeded, External Devices(Keyboard, mouse, docking station, etc), Resource Permission(text box?), Email groups
        [DisplayName("Needs Credit Card")]
        public bool NeedsCredit { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SoftwareNeeded:

```
namespace HROnboarding.Domain.Entities
{
    public class SoftwareNeeded
    {
        //Primitive Properties
        public int SoftwareNeededId { get; set; }
        public string SoftwareName { get; set; } //piece of software (GIMP, VS13, etc)
        public bool IsNeeded { get; set; } //whether or not it is needed by the user
    }
}
```

--**Controllers**--

NewHireController:

```
namespace HROnboarding.WebUI.Controllers    
{
    public class NewHireController : Controller
    {
        private INewHiresRepository repository;
        public NewHireController(INewHiresRepository newHireRepository)
        {
            //instantiate repository
            this.repository = newHireRepository;
        }
        //
        // GET: /NewHire/
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(repository.NewHires);
        }

        public ViewResult NewHiresView()
        {
            return View(repository.NewHires);
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: There is also a corresponding SoftwareController as well, identical to the NewHireController.*

These models correspond to interfaces (repositories) looking something like this for each model:

```
namespace HROnboarding.Domain.Interfaces
{
    public interface INewHiresRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<NewHire> NewHires { get; }
        int SaveNewHire(NewHire newHire);
        NewHire GetById(int Id);

    }
}
```

As I said, I'm attempting to use partial views for each model:

```
@model IEnumerable<HROnboarding.Domain.Entities.NewHire>

@if (Model != null)
{
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        First Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Last Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Department
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @item.FirstName
                               .
                               .
                               .
```

I'm using one of these partial views per each model, wrapping them into references through a primary index view like so:

```
@using HROnboarding.Domain.Entities
@using HROnboarding.Domain.Interfaces
@model IEnumerable<HROnboarding.Domain.Entities.NewHire>

<h2>List</h2>
<p>
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("NewHiresView")
    </div>
    <div>
        @*@Html.Partial("Softwares")*@ @*<-------Can't just add this in?*@
    </div>
</p>
@*<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>*@
@*<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
```

But when I go to add the various partials into the index view, I can only add the NewHire. When I add the Softwares view, it throws an unhandled exception:

> Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is
>   of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[HROnboarding.Domain.Entities.NewHire]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[HROnboarding.Domain.Entities.SoftwareNeeded]'

As I said, I must be missing something fundamental here, as I feel I'm making it too complicated. Also not sure if this is "too much" background info, but I hope my question is clear.

Comment: By definition, you can only have one model, there is no such thing as multiple models per view. If you need to render data from several different classes, you can create a viewmodel specific to your view and include those classes you want to render as members of your viewmodel. And you probably want to use editor templates instead of partial views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something the same, only difference I only pass one view model to my main view, each of these are then rendered using

`@Html.Partial("ViewName", Model)`

The veiw model is an aggregate of some domain objects.  Some of these views are contained within a single form, thus posting back the complete model. and others are ajax enabled and only send back parts of the viewModel as JSON objects.

Perhaps try simplifying your views and making use of view models utilizing partial

Comment: So you have a view model that contains all model classes, that in turn is rendered in a main view?

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm not all the models, only the models that the current view structure cares about. For example the entity being edited and lists containing drop down values that need to be displaying in the view.

Comment: Right, but for my example, I want it to all go into one form. The form uses all data entities before submitting. Or do you mean ones that _immediately_ correspond with the data in that same "field"?

Comment: No I would then use all the entities that you require inside of that one view model. Think of the view model as exactly what it says, it's the model that the view requires to function. Then when posting back the controller accepts the same view model and runs the persistence, validation etc on the view model

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamental issue is that you are trying to use your Data Entities as View Models.

You have two options:

**Quick and Dirty:** Pass your Data Entities to the View via the ViewBag.

**"Correct" MVC:** Create ViewModels for each View. The models would include properties which correspond with your Data Entities

Comment: Are there any resources you can link that would pertain to my specific situation? I want to go about things the "correct" way, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it. When you say a viewmodel for each view, would those viewmodels include references to my model classes?